# Is there an equivalent to PHP's `date_default_timezone_set()` that works in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

This works great in PHP

```
date_default_timezone_set('my/timezone');

$actualDate = date('Y-m-d');
```

Now when doing queries, I like to do

```
INSERT INTO articles (title, insert_date) VALUES ('My Title', now())
```

The problem with this is the `now()` in the MySQL is different to what it would be had it been calculated in PHP (and therefore against the timezone being set).

Is there a way, say a SQL query, to set the default timezone for MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: How about this?  If your system is one that has no zoneinfo database (for example, Windows or HP-UX), you can use the package of pre-built time zone tables that is available for download at the MySQL Developer Zone:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html

Comment: I downloaded these... but don't know what to do with them... I feel like a noob this afternoon :S

Comment: I give up for now... I just made date_time::getIsoDateTime()  :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html

> If you have the SUPER  privilege, you can set the global server time zone value at runtime with this statement:
>
> `mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;`
>
> Per-connection time zones. Each client that connects has its own time zone setting, given by the session time_zone variable. Initially, the session variable takes its value from the global time_zone variable, but the client can change its own time zone with this statement:
>
> `mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;`

Comment: Thanks Paolo; where can I get a list of accepted timezones? Thanks :)

Comment: "The allowable values for --timezone or TZ are system-dependent. Consult your operating system documentation to see what values are acceptable."

Comment: I would assume that whatever PHP is able to use MySQL would be able to use... http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Yeh, I would of thought too, but it was hitting me with "There was an SQL error: Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Australia/Brisbane' - SET time_zone = `Australia/Brisbane`" which is what I've used in PHP for months...

Answer (score 1):

Something you could try is to store all of your date/times in UTC. So, you would use

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$actualDate = date('Y-m-d');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO articles (title, insert_date) VALUES ('My Title', UTC_TIMESTAMP())
```

Then you would convert the UTC date/time to the timezone of the user before displaying it.

Comment: This looks like a good way of doing it, however the site is bound to it's localisation. But I will definitely consider this in the future +1

Answer (score 0):

I usually set the MySQL server to Greenwich Mean Time, and then use gmdate instead of date in PHP. Keeps everything in GM Time so if you move to another server, or have 2 in different time zones, things don't get all screwed up.