# Can't change the Default timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, timestamp

I use http://www.webhostingpad.com/ for hosting my website, but I really need to change the default timezone to Europe/Tallinn time. I wrote to them and they said that they can't change it for me.

So I tried **date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Tallinn');** but the php.ini overrides it or smth. Because if I checked the phpinfo it still had "America/Chicago" or smth.

I also can't change the php.ini file, but I made a copy of it and add it to directory where I can change it. Added **date.timezone = "Europe/Tallinn"** and also tried **ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Tallinn');** It changed the default timezone in phpinfo, but if in mysql database I use: **on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**

**And it adds the date still 8 hours wrong.**

Does any one have any suggestion how to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

As anything didn't lead to solution and my service provider said: if you upgrade your contract, then you can change the mySQL timezone.

So now I'm trying to get some result by adding current datetime with php.

```
INSERT INTO points  (user_id, game_id, points, dateRight) VALUES($userid, $game, $points, sysdate()+3600)");
```

<< This didn't help. Can anybody help? Thanks! :)

Comment: have you tried this?? ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Tallinn');

Comment: ok..then you need to check your mysql Server Time Zone ..check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: Tried: SET time_zone = '+2:00'; Didn't worked for me.
And for: SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+2:00'; -  Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation

Answer (score 0):

Try to [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) your current timezone.

Comment: Tried setlocale(LC_ALL, "et_ET"); - still the same.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the question. So in PHP it works as expected and the timezone is correct? But now you having issues in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

you can set php default timezone with date_default_timezone_set, for mysql look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896305/is-there-an-equivalent-to-phps-date-default-timezone-set-that-works-in-mysq)

Why mysql because, timestamp on update current_timestamp uses mysql default timezone.